# How to avoid line breaks if there is space?

Tags: html, css

In my project, i have to show iframe code inside the texarea. I have shown iframe but the problem is it display by breaking the line.

https://imghostr.com/ae97ae_q8i

Like this. I want it to display without out breaking the line even if there is space.

Comment: Why don't you use "input" then?

Comment: Why not using a simple input instead of textarea?

Comment: @AliSheikhpour If i put it in input box then it shows me "[object HTMLIFrameElement]" inside the box instead of iframe

Comment: @AliSheikhpour If i put it in input box then it shows me "[object HTMLIFrameElement]" inside the box instead of iframe

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS property `white-space: nowrap;` on your textarea

Answer (score 0):

Mehtod 1: Use input instead of textarea. Avoid using nestes single quotes or double quotes. use single quote for value attribute and double quote in inner code:

```html
<input value='<iframe src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/uploadImage" style="width:100%;height:400px"'>
```

Method 2: A textarea with `white-space:nowrap`

```html
<textarea style="width:150px;height:100px;white-space:nowrap"><iframe src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/uploadImage"></textarea>
```